# How to prove $ \lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} \cos(1/x) $ does not exist

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

How do I prove that this limit does not exist?

$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} \cos(1/x)
$$

When plugging in $0^+$ in $x$ we get $-\infty \times \cos(\infty)$ which is undefined. however I am trying to prove that it doesn't exist and am not capable? Do I use the squeeze rule or toast rule? I have tried a few different ways and haven't managed anything

Comment: Choose points $x$ close to $0$ with $\cos (\frac 1  x)=1$.

Comment: Adding to Kavi comment, use the definition of limit and try to negate it.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) about how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: See what happens if you approach $0$ along the two different sequences $x_n  = \frac{2}{{\pi (2n + 1)}},\; y_n  = \frac{1}{{2\pi n}}.
$

Comment: What is the toast rule?

Answer (score 2):

we can write
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} \cos\frac{1}{x}$$
Take $$x_n=\frac{1}{2n\pi}, x'_n= \frac{1}{(2n+1)\pi}$$
$f(x_n)=(2\pi n)^{1/2}\cos (2\pi n)>0$ and
$f(x'_n)=((2n+1)\pi)^{1/2} \cos((2n+1)\pi)<0$, these two values are essentially unequal. the $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x)$ does not exist.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I think that's not enough. Though they have different signs, but may converge both to $0$. (Additional note should be boundedness of $\cos$ function).

Comment: @kolobokish He has miswritten the value of $f(x_n)$, which should be $(2\pi n)^{1/2}$. And it works.

Comment: @Oolongmilktea It works because in fact $f(x_n)>1$ and $f(x'_n)<-1$. But what is written, $>0$ and $<0$, isn't enough.

Comment: @Oolongmilktea My comment was not intended to somehow argue. Just wanted to correct ambiguity regarding the formulation of answer.  )) That's all. I pretty much understand that the answer is correct, and the author knows what he writes.))

Answer (score 0):

As for any $\delta$, $0<x<\delta\implies \dfrac 1x$ is unbounded,

$$\max_{0<x<\delta}\left|\frac1{\sqrt x}\cos\dfrac1x\right|=\max_{0<x<\delta}\frac1{\sqrt x},$$ which is obviously unbounded.

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{\cos(x^{-1})}{\sqrt{x}}=\lim_{n\to + \infty} \frac{\cos((\frac{1}{n\pi})^{-1})}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{n\pi}}}=\sqrt{\pi} \lim_{n \to +\infty} (-1)^n \sqrt{n}$$
And that limit clearly does not exist, so initial limit doesn't exist.